# How to convert autoload class to a static class

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am trying to implement a API into an existing PHP framework. However, the API uses namespaces and autoload function which causes my coding to show "don't find static file" error messages.

May I know how should I go about tackle this issue?

1. Convert the [autoload](https://github.com/binaryage/php-ga/blob/master/src/autoload.php) class to static class/method class?
   I tried put a static keyword beside function but it is not working.
2. Don't use the autoload class and remove all the namespace?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't imagine what your code looks like and what framework you're using. Please provide some code and information for us, especially about that error. Don't you use composer?

Comment: @SenseException Basically i am implementing this php google analytics code into an old shopping cart solution. I only have basic php knowledge and not really sure what composer do you mean.

Comment: @SenseException I tried implement this code into the "controller" file of the php framework that deal with generating successful order page. When I try to implement this https://github.com/binaryage/php-ga/tree/master/src , it show "Don't find static file "UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics" error. I believe it is linked to the namespace and autoloader conflicts but i'm not sure how should I tackle this issue.